# Use nmake to build app (release mode + .PDB file) by command line

Tags: c++, nmake

Is there any option to build an **C++ application** by `nmake` command which will output an **execute** file (in **release** mode) and its `pdb` file?

Comment: _nmake_ runs a _Makefile_. In that _Makefile_, the _linker_ options are specified (if not, defaults are used). According to [/PDB linker option MSDN  page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kwx19e36(v=vs.100).aspx): __Use /PDB:filename to specify the name of the PDB file. If /DEBUG is not specified, the /PDB option is ignored.__ In _Release_ mode _/DEBUG_ is not passed to the linker.